# How set parameter in a bean of conf spring in scope step

Tags: spring

My work :

```
<bean class="com....JpaPagingItemReader">
    <property name="queryString" 
        value="SELECT toto FROM MyToto toto WHERE toto.createDate > :calculDate"/>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="calculDate" value-ref="calculDate" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="${totoStep.pageSize}"/>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="calculDate" factory-bean="dates" factory-method="getDate" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="totoStep"/>
</bean>
```

Produce this error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Sat Nov 01 00:00:00 CET 2014] was not matching type [java.util.Date]

I have a spring component `Dates` contain `Map<String, Date>` I can access with `getDate(String)` method.
When I log parameters :

```
LOGGER.trace("query.setParameter({}:String, {}:{})", me.getKey(), 
    me.getValue(), me.getValue().getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Show :

> JpaPagingItemReader:167 - query.setParameter(calculDate:String, Sat Nov 01 00:00:00 CET 2014:$Proxy36)

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [spring language expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef) to get the wanted value.

```
<bean class="com....JpaPagingItemReader">
    <property name="queryString" 
        value="SELECT toto FROM MyToto toto WHERE toto.createDate > :calculDate"/>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="calculDate" value="#{dates.date['totoStep']}" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="${totoStep.pageSize}"/>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. But another would be welcome.
In my case, it is not necessary to be in scope step . I can just :

```
<bean id="calculDate" factory-bean="dates" factory-method="getDate" 
    lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="totoStep"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks to the person knowing how not having $Proxy on all Object set in scope step and force us to use interfaces (not possible in this case).